# Is fmod incorrect?

Tags: c++

Given the following doubles, does `fmod` return the correct value?

```
    double x = .090;
    double y = .003;
    double r = fmod(x, y);
    // r = 0.0029999999999999949
```

Why doesn't r = 0?

Comment: ... because, in general, floating point numbers can't exactly represent base-10 fractions.  This question has been answered here hundreds of times already.

Comment: consider removing tag visual-c++ this has nothing to do with visual-c++

Answer (score 6):

Because, like most decimal fractions, these numbers can't be represented exactly by a binary floating point format. To see what values are actually being used:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    printf("%.20f %.20f\n", .090, .003);
}

Output: 0.08999999999999999667 0.00300000000000000006
```

These small rounding errors mean that the first value is slightly less than an exact multiple of the second, hence the result you see.

You may want to allow a small tolerance for error:

```
if (r > y - some_small_value) {
    r = 0;
}
```

Comment: I realized it after I posted it that it was the inputs. It's Friday, my mind is on going home :).

Answer (score 3):

This type of question can be resolved by reading a paper entitled [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+every+computer+scientist+should+know+about+floating-point+arithmetic).

Your machine uses a binary representation for floating-point numbers which cannot exactly represent the rational number 3/1000 = 0.003.

Of course, the machine can print its approximation of 0.003 as `"0.003"`, but that's being done by the formatted printing code inside `printf`, when it rounds off the value to a given number of decimal digits.

The difference between the printed, decimal versions of floating-point values and their actual internal values can create problems for the programmer or user who isn't aware of the issues.